# Python: Automating Emails

Tags: python

Here is what I want to achieve :

1) An email should be sent to using **"email address & details"** mentioned in a Google docs/excel file. 
2) The email should also pick up some content from a web page .i.e **Title, URL** etc. & include in the email sent.

Do let me know, how or where do I begin?

Answer (score 1):

Start reading this http://docs.python.org/library/email

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by writing something that just downloads the document and writes it to file. Python has a module for using most of its services: Youtube, gmail, docs, etc.

You could get the gdata client here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list

And a good place to start would be here: http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

Comment: Thanks for these links. Atleast, I know where to begin.